# Найти километровый участок с наибольшей разницей

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

Я столкнулась с проблемой в Postres. У меня есть таблица "Information" со столбцами: id, id_Brand, date, time, id_TypeOfAccident, longitude, latitude ,victims, geometry.  Мне нужно найти километровый участок с наибольшей разницей между количеством аварий днем и ночью. Я не понимаю, как найти участок дороги.
Пыталась сделать такой запрос, но безуспешно.

```sql
SELECT info1.latitude, info1.longitude, info2.latitude, info2.longitude
FROM "Information" AS info1, "Information" AS info2 
WHERE info1.ID <><> info2.ID 
  AND (SELECT 111.111 * DEGREES(
        ACOS(LEAST(1,0, COS(RADIANS(info1.latitude)))
        * COS(RADIANS(info2.latitude))
        * COS(RADIANS(info1.longitude - info2.longitude))
        + SIN(RADIANS(info1.latitude))
        * SIN(RADIANS(info2.latitude)))))
       FROM "Information" AS info2) <= 1
```

Comment: Для решения задачи следует сначала выстроить имеющиеся точки по порядку и посчитать их расстояние от некоей базовой (начальной, к примеру) точки маршрута. После чего посчитать оконный COUNT(), где окно - это от текущей точки и в пределах километра, и взять запись с максимальным значением этого количества.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы расписать данный код?

Comment: Не-а... в вопросе тупо нехватает данных для воспроизведения. Как минимум - выкладывайте CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO с примером данных и показывайте требуемый ответ для этих данных с подробными пояснениями.

Comment: PS. Вообще-то в ПостГИС есть функция, которая считает расстояние между двумя точками, так что какой смысл возиться с синусами и радианами?

Answer (score 0):

Пример реализации финального отбора (после построения маршрута, с расстояниями от исходной точки):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY point_coordinate ASC 
                          RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) cnt
    FROM test
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
ORDER BY cnt DESC 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=26fd67d7d0917661f88dc450b38a2f98)